# SQL query tutorials

Tags: sql

Given the following tables (i wrote it in this manner to keep things neater)

```
airline (name, telephone, designator)
flight (name, number, departure, arrival, origin, destination)
airport (name, country, designator)
```

I would like to print the pairs of names of competing airline. Airlines with the same route or having the same origin and destination. Removing the symmetry from the result as an airline does not compete with itself. Would this work

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name
FROM airline a1, airline a2, flight f1, flight f2
WHERE 
a1.name <> a2.name
AND a1.name = f1.name
AND a2.name = f2.name
AND f1.origin = f2.origin
AND f1.destination = f2.destination
GROUP BY 
a1.name, a2.name;
```

Then, print the names of the airlines that have flights to all listed airports in thailand.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name
FROM airline a, flight f
WHERE f.destination = ALL(SELECT a.name
                    FROM airport a
                    WHERE a.country = 'Thailand');
```

Comment: Duplicates itself? You should just try it: http://sqlfiddle.com Also you may have to connect your tables. Does a flight know for which airline it is flying?

Answer (score 0):

The first query seem fine, but the second won't work as using `ALL` in the way you do states that the destination must be equal to all the airport names returned from the subquery which it obviously can't be.

A solution is to write the query on the form *show the name of all airlines for which there are no Thai airports that are not in the list of destinations that the airline traffics*:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM airline a
JOIN flight f ON a.name = f.name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name 
    FROM airport 
    WHERE country = 'Thailand'             
    AND name NOT IN (
       SELECT destination 
       FROM flight
       WHERE f.name = name
       )
    )
GROUP BY a.name;
```